# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version

Tags: java, linkedin-jsapi, chilkat

Downloaded `chilkat-9.5.0-jdk11-x64` from chilkat site which had the jars and a dll file. Running in Windows 10. Trying to run the code from Chilkat to connect to LinkedIn. Both my `java` and `javac` is in version `1.8`. Getting the below error. Any help is appreciated.

```
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=com/chilkatsoft/CkOAuth2, offset=6
```

Comment: Obviously the jar you use is not compiled for java 8. Try running your app with java 7.

Answer (score 1):

Chilkat provides builds for JDK6, 7, 8, 10, and 11.   Make sure you download the build that matches your JDK version:   https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java.asp